# Is it right to say "to help learning"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I am comparing two products and want to say:

> Inter-comparisons of FGH products with other products at the global scale help to learning the regions where they agree or diffe.

I wonder if help to learning is correct.

Comment: _to help learning_ as in your title can be correct - but _help to learning_ is not. The comparisons can help to learn, or help to _find out_ or help to _discover_. Whichever word you pick, just use a bare infinitive, not a gerund.

Comment: _identify_ would be a better word choice than learning.

Comment: Typically, 'facilitate' is used; I'd avoid 'help' altogether: 


Inter-comparisons of FGH products with other products at the global scale facilitate learning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No "help to learning" is grammatically incorrect. Just use the infinitive, "to learn:"

> Inter-comparisons of FGH products with other products at the global scale *help to 
>   learn* the regions where they agree or differ.

Or, even better:

> Inter-comparisons of FGH products with other products at the global
>   scale *help one learn* the regions where they agree or differ.

Comment: The three-word sequence in question *can* be grammatical in sentences where "help" is a noun, such as "The breakfast-in-the-schools program has proven to be a significant *help to learning."* This probably accounts for persistent non-zero frequency on ngram, 1861-75 and 1977-2008. (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=help+to+learning&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chelp%20to%20learning%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase might be better formulated, 'Comparison between FGH products at the global scale helps in understanding the similarities and differences between the various offerings.'

Answer (score 0):

Help in learning. Or help to learn.This book helped me in learning English

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).